# Post Ajax call says Get not allowed

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax with post method but it keep poping me this error

> An attempt was made to call the method \u0027SendEmail\u0027 using a GET request, which is not allowed

Here is the js

```
var obj = { name: name, company: company, country: country, email: email, msg: Msg }
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "ContactUs.aspx/SendEmail",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    data: json,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (data) {
        var a = 3;
    },
    error:function(a,b){
        var a = 43;
    }
})
```

and here is the server side on c#

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendEmail(string name, string company, string country, string email, string msg)
{
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using .asmx or web api?

Comment: niether of them

Comment: is sendEmail a method within code behind of some .aspx page ?

Comment: Yes. i even tried to add `    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]` but with no succses

Comment: No, you can't do this way, its better to add .asmx file, write method there and then call with jquery.

Comment: I can. this is not the first website im doing but it is the first im doing on this computer and for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: I think the context of my answer and your question is different. I was talking about web services but you want to just call a serverside method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow this way:
Your backend method which you already decorated with `[WebMethod]` and added a reference of `using System.Web.Services;`, I've changed the method to return something so it can be verified whether it works or not.

```
[WebMethod]
public static String sendEmail(string param)
{
 return "Your String";
}
```

within your `.aspx` page, add `scriptManager` for enabling client side calling to your code behind methods

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Finally within your `JQuery script`, call the method like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
PageMethods.sendEmail("", onSuccess);
function onSuccess(response)
{
  alert(response);
}});
```

[image: And here is the output within browser]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! but do you know why it was considered as get?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [HttpPost] instead of [WebMethod] and remove static.
Is it a REST API or MVC?

Comment: Given the .aspx page extension and the use of `[WebMethod]` in the first place it would be reasonable to surmise it's WebForms. Therefore WebAPI's `[HttpPost]` isn't applicable here.

Comment: Someone else maybe?